# Getting encoding issues using an old DBF with JDBC - ODBC

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, foxpro, dbf

I've been developing a Java project to query an old DBF FoxPro Database via an ODBC Connector, no problems at all, Tables and SQL are fetching fine.

The table is written in portuguese and is apparently encoded in CP860/IBM860. However, I'm getting trouble with the special character "á". Where it should appear "Mário" is showing "Mßrio". All the other special characters such as "í" or "â" are fine.

```
prop.put("charSet", "cp860");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MYODBC", prop);
```

What could I do?

Comment: If you are trying to use Cp860 and get ß, while you are expecting á, then you are probably using the wrong codepage. Eg in Cp860, ß is byte 0xE1, in Cp1252 byte 0xE1 is á (but 1252 is also not the right one because other characters don't seem to match).

Comment: Yeah, I tested and it didn't work. All other characters went wrong.

Comment: The other possibility is that FoxPro or DBF had their own codepages or did some mangling (I seem to vaguely recall issues like that, but can't recall specifics; too long ago).

Comment: You can ask the codepage of a table using VFP's CPDBF() function. Not sure how you do that in the scenario you're working in, but if you can send a function call, that should give you what you need.